# align input text vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a input text element whose height is adjusted and the text is aligned to right.

How can I align it vertically (on baseline)?

I tried adding some padding to the input elememt at the top and it works.
However, I would like to know if there is any property that can be set to align it vertically.

I also tried to set display: inline-block and vertical-align : text-bottom but didn't work.

This is my input element:

```
<input id="display" type="text" />
```

Here is the css code :

```
form #display {
    height: 10 %;
    width: 100 %;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(12, 37, 30);
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Gotham Rounded Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Can you push your code on jsfiddle or here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of solution,

```
vertical-align: middle
```

another one

```
input[type=text] {
 height: 15px; 
 line-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Tried. Not working. I've attached my code. Note: adding padding-top works but i would like to now  if there is any property to align it vertically.